# Product Quantity Deduction On Condition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2000

I've a requirement to deduct product quantity on a condition. It seems little bit complicated and not sure how to do it using sql query. Here is the concept on it: Product means here raw material. For production purpose, we have to deduct raw materials from stock. There are few rules to follow:

**Table - ProductEntry:**

i) Products are purchased with PO (Purchase order) and invoice number from the supplier. There is a condition in this case. Suppose, 100 products for product id 1001 has been purchased and it came into two sections as follows:

```
Id - ProductId - PO - Invoice no - Quantity - Price - EntryDate

1st section: 1 - 1001 - PO-102 - Inv-122 - 20 - 200 - 2017-07-10 10:00:00

2nd section: 2 - 1001 - PO-102 - Inv-122 - 80 - 800 - 2017-07-10 11:00:00

             3 - 1002 - PO-102 - Inv-122 - 20 - 400 - 2017-07-10 10:00:00
```

Here starts the game. In many cases, the raw material or product may come into multiple sections or fully at a time I mean suppose 100 pieces total.

ii) Now after it has been purchased, it has to get into the store and there is another procedure. Each purchased product should be received with a IP (import permit) number separately as follows:

**Table - IpEntry:**

```
Id - ProductId - Invoice no - IP - AnotherProductId

1 - 1001 - Inv-122 - IP2244 - 2

2 - 1001 - Inv-122 - IP2244 - 2

3 - 1002 - Inv-122 - IP2244 - 4
```

iii) After receiving the products, it should be used for production purpose, that means, there will be consumption. In consumption, the first entered product or raw material should be used. That means, if product id 1001 has to be deducted, then the first entered should be deducted based on '**EntryDate**' as it has entered at the min. time 10:00:00 on the same date. So for deduction or consumption, following should take place:

**Table - Consumption:**

Id - Consumption no - AnotherProductId - Quantity

```
1 - Con-122 - 2 - 10

3 - Con-122 - 4 - 10
```

So the final output will be the following:

```
Id - AnotherProductId - Stock - Quantity Used - Remaining Balance
1 - 2 - 10 - 10 - 100
2 - 4 - 10 - 10 - 200
```

I am not sharing the sql query here as it is supposed to be not accurate and simple enough using `INNER JOIN` and `MIN` functions that returns the following:

```
  Id - AnotherProductId - Stock - Quantity Used - Remaining Balance
   1 - 2 - 10 - 10 - 100
   2 - 2 - 10 - 10 - 100 //It returns **AnotherProductId or ProductId - 1001 or 2** twice as it should only return once
   3 - 4 - 10 - 10 - 200
```

I am not sure how to do deal with the above scenario specifically same product with different quantity and little bit confused.

Here is the script for better understanding:

```
USE [Demo]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[ProductEntry]    Script Date: 07/19/2017 20:37:41 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProductEntry](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ProductId] [int] NULL,
    [PO] [nvarchar](60) NULL,
    [Invoice No] [nvarchar](60) NULL,
    [Quantity] [float] NULL,
    [Price] [float] NULL,
    [EntryDate] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ProductEntry] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[ProductEntry] ON
INSERT [dbo].[ProductEntry] ([Id], [ProductId], [PO], [Invoice No], [Quantity], [Price], [EntryDate]) VALUES (1, 1001, N'PO-102', N'Inv-122', 20, 200, CAST(0x0000A7AC00A4CB80 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[ProductEntry] ([Id], [ProductId], [PO], [Invoice No], [Quantity], [Price], [EntryDate]) VALUES (2, 1001, N'PO-102', N'Inv-122', 80, 800, CAST(0x0000A7AC00B54640 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[ProductEntry] ([Id], [ProductId], [PO], [Invoice No], [Quantity], [Price], [EntryDate]) VALUES (3, 1002, N'PO-102', N'Inv-122', 20, 400, CAST(0x0000A7AC00A4CB80 AS DateTime))
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[ProductEntry] OFF
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[IpEntry]    Script Date: 07/19/2017 20:37:41 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[IpEntry](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ProductId] [int] NULL,
    [Invoice No] [nvarchar](60) NULL,
    [IP] [nvarchar](60) NULL,
    [AnotherProductId] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_IpEntry] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[IpEntry] ON
INSERT [dbo].[IpEntry] ([Id], [ProductId], [Invoice No], [IP], [AnotherProductId]) VALUES (1, 1001, N'Inv-122', N'IP2244', 2)
INSERT [dbo].[IpEntry] ([Id], [ProductId], [Invoice No], [IP], [AnotherProductId]) VALUES (2, 1001, N'Inv-122', N'IP2244', 2)
INSERT [dbo].[IpEntry] ([Id], [ProductId], [Invoice No], [IP], [AnotherProductId]) VALUES (3, 1002, N'Inv-122', N'IP2244', 4)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[IpEntry] OFF
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Consumption]    Script Date: 07/19/2017 20:37:41 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Consumption](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Consumption no] [nvarchar](40) NULL,
    [AnotherProductId] [int] NULL,
    [Quantity] [float] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Consumption] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Consumption] ON
INSERT [dbo].[Consumption] ([Id], [Consumption no], [AnotherProductId], [Quantity]) VALUES (1, N'Con-122 ', 2, 10)
INSERT [dbo].[Consumption] ([Id], [Consumption no], [AnotherProductId], [Quantity]) VALUES (2, N'Con-122 ', 4, 10)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Consumption] OFF
```

Comment: **Note:** The deduction of the product should continue until the quantity becomes zero.

Comment: In your explanation how stock and Quantity Used both are same - 10 & 10?

Comment: Because total quantity was 20 for both and after usage (deducting 10), it became 10 and 10.

Comment: So finally you need to get 3 records as you explained in your last table - with columns: Id - AnotherProductId - Stock - Quantity Used - Remaining Balance ?  Here again Id 2 should have stock 80 right as you consumed only Id 1 & 3?

Comment: No. The other one (See the final output section). This is simply FIFO using `DateTime`. So the firstly entered product or raw material should be deducted from the stock. In my example, for 1001, firstly entered stock is 20 and it's deducted first.

Comment: I've tried a sample query but not close enough. Will be sharing it. If you could suggest anything, that would be more helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you expected result. Please try.

```
    ;WITH CTE AS (
select DISTINCT ProductID,AnotherProductId,Balance,
    CASE WHEN Balance>=0 THEN 'P' ELSE 'N' END Flag, row_number() over(partition by AnotherProductId order by Balance) RID
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT P.ProductID,I.AnotherProductId,(P.Quantity-C.Quantity) 'Balance'  
        FROM [ProductEntry] P INNER JOIN [IpEntry] I ON I.ProductID=P.ProductId
        INNER JOIN (SELECT [AnotherProductId],SUM([Quantity]) [Quantity] FROM [Consumption] GROUP BY [AnotherProductId]) C ON C.AnotherProductId=I.AnotherProductId
      )A
)
select T.AnotherProductId,Balance as Stock, C.Quantity as 'Quantity Used',MIN((P.Price *(P.Quantity-C.Quantity)/P.Quantity))  'Remaining Balance'
FROM [ProductEntry] P INNER JOIN CTE T ON T.ProductID=P.ProductId AND (RID=1 OR Flag='N')
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ProductId,AnotherProductId FROM [IpEntry]) I ON I.ProductID=P.ProductId
INNER JOIN (SELECT [AnotherProductId],SUM([Quantity]) [Quantity] FROM [Consumption] GROUP BY [AnotherProductId]) C ON C.AnotherProductId=I.AnotherProductId
GROUP BY T.AnotherProductId,Balance, C.Quantity
```

Comment: I run your query @Rajesh Bhat. It works but one issue. The quantity remains fixed to my given sample and it doesn't get deducted when I again give input to deduct the quantity from the **Consumption** table for a specific product suppose `AnotherProductId` 2. By the way, I have to use `MIN(DateTime)` for the product consumption.

Comment: Yeah, actually it is deducting from the second record of ProductEntry table if you add one more record in Consumption table. Will relook into the query.

Comment: Made a small correction to my answer. This looking good now. Please try.

Comment: It's working as expected. Thanks a lot. I am bothering you again. Suppose, for `AnotherProductId 2`, the stock is already zero and there are two entries for the `ProductId` or `AnotherProductId` (1001 or 2) with different quantities. So it should get the stock from the second one means another stock is 80.

Comment: Yes, am working on that scenario too..it should make first record as 0 and pick from second record right?

Comment: Yes, perfect @Rajesh Bhat.

Comment: @AT-2017: If the answer is correct, please do mark the same.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected to cover all the scenarios.

```
SELECT DISTINCT P.ProductID,P.Quantity,-1 Flag,C.[Quantity] Balance
INTO #TMP 
FROM [ProductEntry] P
INNER JOIN [IpEntry] I ON I.ProductID=P.ProductId 
        INNER JOIN (SELECT [AnotherProductId],SUM([Quantity]) [Quantity] FROM [Consumption] GROUP BY [AnotherProductId])C ON C.AnotherProductId=I.AnotherProductId

DECLARE @Counter INT=1
WHILE((SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM #TMP WHERE Flag=-1 )=1)
BEGIN
    UPDATE T SET T.Balance = T.Balance-T.Quantity,
                 T.Quantity = CASE WHEN T.Quantity-T.Balance>=0 THEN T.Quantity-T.Balance ELSE 0 END,
                 T.Flag = CASE WHEN T.Quantity-T.Balance>=0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END

    FROM (SELECT  ProductId,Quantity,row_number() over (partition by ProductId order by Quantity)RID FROM [ProductEntry])P
            INNER JOIN [IpEntry] I ON I.ProductID=P.ProductId and P.RID=@Counter
            INNER JOIN (SELECT ProductId,Quantity,Flag,Balance,row_number() over (partition by ProductId order by Quantity)RID FROM #TMP ) T ON T.ProductID=P.ProductID and T.RID=@Counter
            INNER JOIN (SELECT [AnotherProductId],SUM([Quantity]) [Quantity] FROM [Consumption] GROUP BY [AnotherProductId])C ON C.AnotherProductId=I.AnotherProductId

    UPDATE T1 SET Balance=T2.Balance
    FROM #TMP T1 INNER JOIN #TMP T2 ON T1.ProductId=T2.ProductId
    WHERE T2.Flag IN (0,1)
    UPDATE T1 SET Flag= (SELECT T2.Flag FROM #TMP T2 WHERE T1.ProductId=T2.ProductId AND T2.Flag=0)
    FROM #TMP T1
    WHERE Flag=0

    SET @Counter=@Counter+1
    SELECT * FROM #TMP
END     
SELECT ProductId,Quantity FROM #TMP --You can add more details by joining with other tables as per your requirement
drop table #TMP
```